# Question about nested while loop rectangle

Tags: javascript, while-loop, nested-loops

I am working on drawing a rectangle using Javascript. Unfortunately, it appears that the outer loop of my nested while isn't working properly. Currently (xy) appears five times on one line and it does not repeat on concurrent lines as expected.

```
    function Art() { 
// row and col are taking input data from the form in index
    //var row = document.getElementById("row").value; 
    //var col = document.getElementById("height").value; 
    var row=5; 
    var col=3;

    var countrow =1; 
    var countcol =1; 
   document.getElementById("magic").innerHTML=("rectangle has "+ row +" rows and "+ col + " columns");

      while (col> countcol){

           while(countrow<=row){ 
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"(XY)";
            countrow++;
           } 
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"<p></p>"; 
        countcol++; 
    }


}
```

Current output for one run: 
(xy)(xy)(xy)(xy)(xy)

Could someone have a look at my code and help me understand my logic error?

Thank you.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD2Rg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop variable `countrow` goes to the value of `row` the first time, but then in the next iteration of the outer `while` loop it does not restart. So then the inner `while` will no longer execute.

Also, your loops seem to be positioned in the wrong order: you should *first* iterate the rows, and then per row iterate the columns.

Fix it by swapping the loops and resetting the inner loop counter in each iteration:

```
var countrow = 1;
while(countrow<=row){ 
    countcol = 1;
    while (countcol<=col){
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"(XY)";
        countcol++;
    } 
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"<p></p>"; 
    countrow++; 
}
```

It would be better if you would use a standard `for` loop for this (instead of `while`):

```
for (let countrow = 0; countrow < row; countrow++){
    for (let countcol = 0; countcol < col; countcol++){
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"(XY)";
    } 
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"<p></p>"; 
}
```

That will at least make it work. I should however add that repeatedly adding content to `innerHTML` is not really best practice.

Here is how it can also be done, with just one assignment to `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=
    Array.from({length: row}, () => "(XY)".repeat(col)).join("<p></p>");
```

Comment: I agree that it is a strange way of doing this however, my assignment has specifically asked to do it this way. What could I do to ensure the outer while executes on the consecutive iterations?

Comment: By swapping the inner loop to the outer the formatting of my output was also changed. Resetting the countrow counter was the solution. Thank you for the help. It's working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

you should add

```
 countrow =1;
```

inside outer loop

and change

```
col> countcol
```

to

```
col>= countcol
```

```js
 Art();

     function Art() { 
// row and col are taking input data from the form in index
    //var row = document.getElementById("row").value; 
    //var col = document.getElementById("height").value; 
    var row=5; 
    var col=3;

    var countrow =1; 
    var countcol =1; 
   document.getElementById("magic").innerHTML=("rectangle has "+ row +" rows and "+ col + " columns");

      while (col>= countcol){  ////Change > to >=
            countrow =1;  ////YOU SHOULD ADD JUST THIS
           while(countrow<=row){ 
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"(XY)";
            countrow++;
           } 
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=document.getElementById('count').innerHTML+"<p></p>"; 
        countcol++; 
    }


}
```

```html
<div id=magic></div>
<div id=count></div>
```